# git error: fatal: Authentication failed for

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to push a branch to a repo on tfs and I am getting this error: fatal: Authentication failed for xxxxxxxxx

I tried adding credentials to the credentials manger as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553671/authentication-failed-on-tfs-server)  but it didn't work

any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: You looked at all the answers on that question?  Namely ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/51848851/10761889?

Comment: yes @Matt I tried them all.. no luck

Answer (score 0):

You can try [using Personal access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=preview-page) by adding an extra header to Git commands. See below:

```
$MyPat = 'yourPAT'
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$MyPat"))
git -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Basic $B64Pat" clone http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/projectName
```

See document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/iis-basic-auth?view=azure-devops-2019) for more information.